# Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_installing() in /home/wadsam5/public_html/dari/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/wp-seo-main.php on line 487

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I installed Yoast SEO plugin on my WordPress website but when I want to activate it, it doesn't activate and this error occurs "Fatal error: Call to undefined function wp_installing() in /home/wadsam5/public_html/dari/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/wp-SEO-main.php on line 487".

For solving these issues I downloaded the old version of Yoast SEO plugin 7.0 and installed it, but it did not work and the same error occurred.

The second way that I guess to solve this issue is to update my Wordpress version 4.1.29 to current version 5.3.2. but I didn't do that till now. because I am not sure if does it solve the problem and also will update the WordPress effect on my site.
My WordPress theme is Quadrum Premium Theme(version: 1.1.1 By Orange Themes).

Would you please help what should I to solve this issue?

Comment: [wp_installing()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_installing/) is a WordPress function that's available from WordPress **4.4.0** and on. Your WordPress version (4.1.29) is too old. Try upgrading to at least 4.4.0 and the error will disappear.

Comment: By updating my WordPress to 4.4.0, so could you tell me does it not change my website? @cabrerahector

Comment: WordPress 4.1 was released over **five years ago**. There are numerous security vulnerabilities that have been fixed since then, as well as great improvements to the core architecture. Things on your site very well may break, but if you want to secure your site *and* use the latest plugins, you'll need to work through the upgrade process. There's a slim chance you could upgrade all the way to 5.3.2 (which I recommend) with no issues, but odds are a few things will break. You may need to set up a development environment or get a developer to do it for you to get your site updated.